# Oozie not able to generate job/worklfow Id for particular workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie

My Oozie command is able to generate job/workflowId for all workflows expect one.
The only difference between this and other workflow is that it has decision on top of every action where it check whether to run this action or skip.

Comment: How does the workflow look like? What is validation error message when you run `-dryrun`?

Comment: Is there any such option -dryrun

Comment: Yes, like this: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Dryrun_of_Coordinator_Job

Comment: No output. Hung up

Comment: This indicates that there may be circular dependency between actions. Can you update question with workflow definition?

Comment: Same workflow was running on HDP 2.5.3 , after upgrade to 2.6 its not working. Sorry that workflow is on VDI can't share.

Comment: There are around 41 decision action , If I decrease number of decision boxes to 25 it take a bit of time to generate workflowId and works,  but If I make it to 30 its hung up,  not able to generate any workflow Id.